# Solrcloud and multiple cores with different schemas

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Recently, I turned on zookeeper with a Windows/Tomcat/Solr implementation (Solr version 4.4) and got it running fine with the `-DzkRun` and `-Dbootsrap_confdir` options.

Understand that this will launch zookeeper as well and tell it to load the configuration from the confdir parameter; however, because I can only point the configuration to one of the cores, both cores are using the same schema.

I found a `shareschema` option in the `solr.xml` files and set that to false, but the single schema still only seems to load for both cores.

Also checked the release notes for the next version of Solr and did not see anything addressing this.

Multiple instances of Tomcat would probably be a way to get around this, but seems like there should be a way to have multiple schemas available with the zookeeper options.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the cores to different collections. Configuration is defined on per collection basis. I think you cannot use the bootstrap_confdir option with several collections. You should upload the configuration to zookeeper in other way, e.g. by using the ZkCli shipped with SOLR. See SolrCloud wiki for details.

Comment: Actually do have cores assigned to different collections. Your answer got me looking more at the zk client and while I could probably push the schema into zk, I would need to rename it from the default schema.xml. What ended up working was to rename the schema for the second collection to schema_collection2.xml and then copy it into the configuration directory of the first collection.  By doing this, the boostrap_confdir pushed both schemas into zk.  I then needed to add a schema=schema_collection2.xml to the core.properties file of the second core on all the servers.